# UsePAM not supported anymore

Tags: ssh, pam, alpine

Running on an alpine docker image an SSH server. Starting the server I get the message:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 24: Unsupported option UsePAM
```

AFAIK `UsePAM` option has been supported for many years into OpenSSH.

I'm running

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Is it deprecated now?

Answer (score 4):

Missed this alpine package:

```
openssh-server-pam
```

Installing it, works and PAM is now supported.

Comment: I've installed this on my Alpine docker container but it didn't change anything. Do you have anything in mind that potentially could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

To add to your answer:

As noted in [Two Factor Authentication With OpenSSH](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Two_Factors_Authentication_With_OpenSSH) `google-authenticator` requires `openssh-server-pam`, as you mention.

One thing that is missed in the tutorials depending on how it was set up was the use of the community repository to solve [a common problem with this package installation](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/issues/153):

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  google-authenticator (missing):
    required by: world[google-authenticator]
```

To set up the repository(ies) to do this correctly, go into 
`/etc/apk/repositories` and uncomment the community version of the repository line you are using:

```
https://<some_mirror>/<ver>/main
https://<some_mirror>/<ver>/community
```

Then, a

```
apk add google-authenticator openssh-server-pam
```

should work.

---

**EDIT**: As of at least Alpine3.X, you should also install `libqrencode`, via

```
apk add libqrencode
```

`google-authenticate` uses this to generate a scan-able QR code so that you don't have to do the manual entry. It will fail gracefully if this is not installed, however it does make things easier.